# GXT checkbox in grid

Tags: java, checkbox, gxt

I need to update the store when the checkbox in the grid cell changed its state: to add or to remove the value from store. how to handle this event?
BTW, I create the checkbox in grid in this way:

```
column = new ColumnConfig();
column.setId("accepted");
column.setHeader("Accepted");
column.setWidth(55);
```

**UPD2:** Now I do the following:
create checkboxes as firstly decided:

```
CheckColumnConfig checkColumn = new CheckColumnConfig("accepted", "", 55);
CellEditor checkBoxEditor = new CellEditor(new CheckBox());        
checkBoxEditor.setToolTip("If you click here server will consider this rule checking your messages");
checkColumn.setEditor(checkBoxEditor);
checkColumn.setHeader("apply");
configs.add(checkColumn);
```

than handle events in the grid like this:
    **UPD3:**

```
grid.addListener(Events.CellMouseUp, new Listener<GridEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(GridEvent be) {
                PropertyItem item;
                    if (grid.getStore().getAt(be.getRowIndex()).isAccepted()){
                        item = new PropertyItem(val1, val2, val3, true);
                    } else {
                        item = new PropertyItem(val1, val2, val3, false);
                    }
                    store.update(item);
                    store.commitChanges();
                    saveProperties(store, customerId, toRemove);
            }
        });
```

this is the right way.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs found [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/Editor.html), you can add a listener to the `CellEditor`'s `Complete` event. In the `Complete` event `Listener`, perform whatever activity you need to accomplish.

**Update**:
Try the following

```
column.setRenderer(new GridCellRenderer() {

    @Override
    public Object render(ModelData model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex, final ListStore store, Grid grid) {
        CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
        box.addListener(Events.Change, new Listener<FieldEvent>() {
             @Override
             public void handleEvent(FieldEvent be) {
                 st.commitChanges();
                 saveProperties(st, customerId, toRemove);

                // I'm not sure what saveProperties is, but see if this works now.
                // this event should DEFINITELY be fired when the checkbox is clicked
                // so if it doesn't work, try changing how you do your code here
                // maybe by doing model.set(property, (Boolean) be.getValue()); or something
             }
        });
        return box;
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure that you create local instances of `CheckBox`, such as `CheckBox box = new CheckBox();` within the `render` method.

I've also edited my answer to show you the listener I think you should use.

Comment: but Listener<CheckChangedEvent>() can't be used with method handleEvent (FieldEvent be). there is inconsistency between checkchangedEvent and FieldEvent

Comment: Oops, should have <FieldEvent> as the Listener generic type. I've updated as appropriate

Comment: that was a question of choosing apropriate event. but now I have another issue: this change doesn't update the value in the store(you know, you need a ListStore to build the grid) and doesn't show it correctly. previously, when I changed any cell the correspondent value changed in the store. or I have to change it myself now?

Comment: Did you try `model.set(property, (Boolean) be.getValue());`? In my own apps, I have not committed through the store, so this isn't my area of expertise, but I would imagine that you could then call `store.commitChanges()`. I'm not 100% sure, here.

Comment: the problem that it acts separately from the store. it doesn't show changes in the store. method store.commitChanges works well

Comment: Try adding a call to `store.update(model);` after you do `model.set(property, (Boolean) be.getValue());` to tell the store that the model has updated.